# Fetching Custom Customer Attributes Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, custom-attributes, customer-attribute

I am trying to fetch a custom attribute value of a customer in magento 2 but I am unable to fetch it

I am using `\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface` class to fetch the custom customer attribute of a customer

I have tried this

```
       $customers = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById(2);
       print_r($customers->getCustomAttributes('enable_alerts'));
```

This returns

```
Array (
    [enable_alerts] => Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValue Object
        (
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [attribute_code] => enable_alerts
                    [value] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

But I need only value of `enable_alerts`.
What I am doing wrong here Is there any other way of fetching customers attribute value I have tried multiple codes and searched every thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This :-**

```
print_r($customers->getCustomAttributes('enable_alerts')->getValue());
```

Comment: Is there a way to filter the customer by custom attributes values ??

Comment: yes you can use addAttributeToFilter to filter data

Comment: Sorry to ask is there a way I can update current custom attribute value?? :)

Comment: yes you can set

Comment: could you please share how

Comment: $customer->getCustomAttributes('enable_alerts','custom_attribute_value');

Comment: try this..................\